# Swift Присвоение данных к пользовательскому массиву

Tags: xcode, swift

Имеется класс с двумя переменными для определения массива

```
   import Foundation


class AddClass: NSObject, NSCoding{

var name500: String
var date500: String



init(name500:String, date500:String) {
    self.name500 = name500
    self.date500 = date500


}
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name500, forKey: "name500")
    aCoder.encode(date500, forKey: "date500")

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name500 = aDecoder.decodeObject (forKey: "name500") as! String
self.date500 = aDecoder.decodeObject (forKey: "date500") as! String

  }


}
```

Есть два массива определенные классом, в которые нужно записать данные из обычных массивов типа String

```
var names: [AddClass] = []
var dates: [AddClass] = []
```

Эти два массива типа String получают значения из парсинга и выглядят так:

```
 nameGame500 = ((url.object(forKey: "links")  as! NSArray).value(forKeyPath: "name")  as! NSArray) as! [String]
 dategame500 = ((url.object(forKey: "links")  as! NSArray).value(forKeyPath: "release_date")  as! NSArray) as! [String]
```

Нужно сделать, что бы

```
var names: [AddClass] = [] был равен nameGame500
var dates: [AddClass] = [] был равен dategame500
```

Таким методом работает только если в классе одна переменная

```
names = nameGame500.map({ AddClass(name500: $0) })
```

но если две,

```
names = nameGame500.map({ AddClass(name500: $0) })
dates = dategame500.map({ AddClass(date500: $0) })
```

то выдает ошибку

```
'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type '[AddClass]'
```

**UPD:**

```
let ss = names.map {names -> [Image] in
        let arrayImage = names.images
        let sv = arrayImage.filter {arrayImage -> Bool in
            let typeUrl = arrayImage.type
            return typeUrl == 1
        }
        return sv
    }
```

Comment: Вам нужно во время маппинга инициализировать вторую переменную тоже. Что-то подобное делать: AddClass(name500: $0, secondName: "")

Comment: так точно не получится, ибо мапаю я тот массив, в который например спарсил имена, а есть массив с датами, и его уже нужно отдельно мапать, из за этого ошибка и выскакивает

Comment: Добавьте тогда более полное описание, то что у вас есть второй массив и вы хотите создать массив объектов на основе данных массивов.

Comment: ну изначально было написано) думал понятно, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Исправил пост, думаю теперь ясно все

Comment: А парсите изначально вы что? JSON?

Comment: да, получаю на выходе массив текстовых имен

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82122/discussion-between-vitaly-and-vladislav-bublik).

Comment: Прикрепите кусок JSON я предложу вам рациональное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал бы так

```
class AddClass: Decodable {

    var name500: String
    var date500: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name500 = "name"
        case date500 = "release_date"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let conteiner = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .name500)
        date500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .date500)
    }
}
```

И структура для разбора JSON

```
struct Response: Decodable {

    var addClasses: [AddClass]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case addClasses = "links"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let conteiner = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        addClasses = try conteiner.decode([AddClass].self, forKey: .addClasses)
    }
}
```

Для получения обьектов

```
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 do {
      let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data) // data: Data
      response.addClasses // -> [AddClass] вот наш масив
 } catch let error {
      print("decoding error: \(error)")
 }
```

---

**UPD**: для картинок можно так сделать

Создаем класс для картинок

```
 class Image: Decodable {

    var type: Int
    var url: URL

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case type
        case url
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let conteiner = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type = try conteiner.decode(Int.self, forKey: .type)
        let urlString = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
        url = URL(string: urlString)!
    }
}
```

и добавляем поле в AddClass

```
 class AddClass: Decodable {

    var name500: String
    var date500: String
    var images: [Image]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name500 = "name"
        case date500 = "release_date"
        case images
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let conteiner = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .name500)
        date500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .date500)
        images = try conteiner.decode([Image].self, forKey: .images)
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Если сложновато пока можете сделать так, когда у вас уже есть 2 массива вы просто на основе их создаете объект:

```
for (index, name500) in nameGame500.enumerated() {
   var game500 = dategame500[index]
   let addClass = AddClass(name500: name500, game500: game500)
   result.append(addClass)
}
```

---

**UPD:** вот, получаете урл картинки для любого типа через вызов метода `myAddClassObject.getImageUrl(for: 1)`

```
class AddClass: Decodable {

    var name500: String
    var date500: String
    var images: [Image]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name500 = "name"
        case date500 = "release_date"
        case images
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let conteiner = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .name500)
        date500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .date500)
        images = try conteiner.decode([Image].self, forKey: .images)
    }

    func getImageUrl(for type: Int) -> URL? {
        let image = images.first{ return $0.type == type }
        return image?.url
    }
}
```

Comment: уже решили проблему, но попробую и ваш способ тоже)
возможно смогу картинки вытащить из json, иначе могу все, кроме ссылок на картинки)))

Comment: т.е. данные из Парсинга мы получили в response.addClasses? а как потом ею воспользоваться, в ней должны же быть name и date?

Comment: Ну так там массив объектов у каждого есть имя , дата и набор картинок. Все по той ссылке которую вы кидали , там вроде по 5-7картинок на каждую запись

Comment: Да, насчет картинок правильно, с этим у меня и были проблемы, вытащить одну картинку из набора
Но я спрашиваю , как потом воспользоваться данными которые мы получили. я их вывожу в таблицу, а как это сделать, я не совсем понимаю) видимо выше головы уже прыгаю)

Comment: Ну можно отфильтровать по типу картинки(не знаю какой вам нужен) а потом загрузить по ссылке и все

Comment: Можно например при помощи Alamofire Image грузить в image view

Comment: сейчас попробую, пока все работает, единственное при входе в приложение висит из за Парсинга, но это решу) с картинками попробую, отпишусь)

Comment: таким же образом доставать картинки по типу? из 5 нужен второй например

    private enum CodingKeys:Int, CodingKey {
        case type = 2
        case url

Comment: Ну можно метод написать у AddClass  который вернёт урл по типу, посмотрите поиск по массиву

Comment: суть понимаю, но пока не выходит) уже недели две вожусь с парсингом картинок) буду пытаться, уже ближе

Comment: я вам в вк написал, если сможете, зайдите пожалуйста

Comment: Андрей, я вроде как отфильтровал картинки по типу равному 1, можете сказать, правильно ли это? в главном посте добавил  внизу

Comment: Можно и так....

Comment: судя по вашим точкам способ г....., но по другому пока не умею) вроде уже и ссылки вытащил, буду пробовать) спасибо за помощь

Comment: Андрей. нужна ваша помощь) никак не могу извлечь картинки, что бы их потом можно было в таблицу привязать к остальному массиву. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, готов к денежному вознаграждению)

Answer (score 1):

По идее так

`let convertedArray = arrayForPars.map({ AddClass(name: $0) })`

Comment: Не выходит, примерно так же пробовал, и все тщетно)

Comment: а нет, сработало, я немного не тот массив тыкал)) с ночной смены пришел, и такие дела) спасибо!

Comment: а вот при добавлении переменных в класс, выдает ошибку 'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type '[AddClass]'

Comment: тогда массив надо объявить как `var` и делать `append( AddClass(name: "string") )`

Comment: исправил пост, посмотрите

Comment: "С одной переменной в классе все работает, но добавляя вторую переменную выдает ошибку" - в какой класс, какая переменная?

Comment: класс в начале поста который, переменная первая name500 с одной ею все работает, добавляю точно такую же переменную в этом класс,но с названием data500 и ошибка

Comment: Вы создали класс, у которого обязательные параметры в конструкторе, следовательно, когда вы добавляете в конструктор новый параметр, то и при методе map вам надо также добавить этот параметр, либо делать в конструкторе data500 необязательным (Optional типом)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно во время создания объекта `AddClass` инициализировать все проперти которые не являются optional или которые не инициализированны по умолчанию.

То как вы парсите данные в 2 разных массива а потом из этих массивов формируте объекты это плохой стиль.

Если изначально вы парсите JSON можно делать что-то подобное (зависит от структуры вашего JSON):

```
var result: [AddClass] = []()

for item in jsonObject {
                guard
                    let departDate = item["name"] as? String,
                    let arrivalDate = item["release_date"] as? String else {
                        return
                }

let addClass = AddClass(name500: String, date500: String)

}
```

Или так:

```
class AddClass: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let releaseDate: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case releaseDate = "release_date"
    }
}
```

Так декодируем JSON в объект AddClass

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   do {
       let result = try decoder.decode([AddClass].self, from: response.data!)
   }
   catch {
          print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
          print(error)
   }
```

**UPD:** Если сложновато пока можете сделать так, когда у вас уже есть 2 массива вы просто на основе их создаете объект:

```
for (index, name500) in nameGame500.enumerated() {
   var game500 = dategame500[index]
   let addClass = AddClass(name500: name500, game500: game500)
   result.append(addClass)
}
```

Comment: выглядит интересно, но пока не знаю, как это все внедрить в проект. Т.е. присвоить обычный массив к пользовательскому классу нельзя? Таким методом, каким я пользуюсь

Comment: последний способ помог, работает хорошо, интересно, чем такой способ может быть плох?)

Comment: понял косяк, при повторном парсинге, данных становится двоем больше из за добавления в массив)